# How to add multiple components in React Native?

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native, expo

**Note: I am new to React Native and have searched up how to do this but found no helpful results** I am using React Native to create an app and want to add multiple components, such as text, buttons, and a text input space, but am having trouble doing so without receiving errors. Is there any way to include multiple components into one javascript document using React Native?

*The code I currently have:*

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{alignItems: 'center'}}>
        <Text style={styles.bigblack}>Sample Bold Text Here</Text>
        <Text>Sample Text Here:</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  bigblack: {
    color: 'black',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: 28,
  },
  red: {
    color: 'red',
  },
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fdf5e6',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },

});
```

*Code I want to add for Text Input:*

```
class UselessTextInput extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <TextInput
        {...this.props} 
        editable = {true}
        maxLength = {40}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default class UselessTextInputMultiline extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      text: 'Useless Multiline Placeholder',
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
     <View style={{
       backgroundColor: this.state.text,
       borderBottomColor: '#000000',
       borderBottomWidth: 1 }}
     >
       <UselessTextInput
         multiline = {true}
         numberOfLines = {4}
         onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text})}
         value={this.state.text}
       />
     </View>
    );
  }
}
```

*Code I want to add for Button:*

```
<Button
  onPress={onPressLearnMore}
  title="Learn More"
  color="#841584"
  accessibilityLabel="Learn more about this button"
/>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create multiple component in same document but can `export default` only one.

So you can create multiple component like below:

```
export class UselessTextInput {}

export class UselessTextInputMultiline {}

export class Button {}
```

while accessing :

```
import {UselessTextInput, UselessTextInputMultiline, Button} from './components/customInput' // change with your respective path
```

if you still want to have single `export default` then:

```
export default class UselessTextInputMultiline {}
```

and while importing

```
import Template,{Button} from './components/customInput'
```

For, exporting multiple component:

```
module.exports = {
    text: UselessTextInput,
    btn: Button
}
```

imports will be like:

```
let txtInput= require('./components/customInput').text;
let btnInput = require('./components/customInput').btn;
```

Comment: Could you explain the `import {UselessTextInput, UselessTextInputMultiline, Button} from './components/customInput' // change with your respective path` Does this mean that I need to create another .js file with these names?

Comment: no, I meant your current js name and path. I was not able to see your file name so I mentioned to change with respective path for your component file.